# How to determine if URLs with different parameter values are "unique"?

Tags: web-crawler

I hope someone can help me out with this.  I'm writing a spider application in PHP that compiles a list of unique URLs from a domain, processes the HTML data on each of those unique URLs, and then generates statistical data about those pages.

My problem has to do with knowing whether a URL I've spidered is truly unique to my list, more specifically, when the parameter values are different.

As an example, here are two URLs collected by my spider that are technically unique (different parameter value for 'replytocom'), but also direct to the same page:

- http://eatocracy.cnn.com/2013/08/02/fda-sets-gluten-free-labeling-standards/?hpt=hp_bn11&replytocom=537479#respond
- http://eatocracy.cnn.com/2013/08/02/fda-sets-gluten-free-labeling-standards/?hpt=hp_bn11&replytocom=537470#respond

These links are the kind you'd find on a blog that makes it easier to reply to specific comments while still using the same response form.  This is where my problem comes in: they're both URLs for the same page, which is data I wouldn't want to reprocess (I'd really only want the original page's URL for processing).  For a blog that uses these sorts of links in all of their comment sections, this would be a big data problem for my spider.

My question is: is there a way to tell if two links with different parameter values are referencing the same page?  The thing that got me wondering is that, for example, YouTube videos with different parameter values really mean different pages.  Short of opening the pages myself and checking, is there a programmatic way to tell if two URLs are loading the same page?

I'd really appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web pages are [supposed to](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139394?hl=en) include `<meta rel="canonical">` tag to answer this question for you.
If present, this will specify the "official" URL for this page; it should be identical for different URLs to the same page.

If this tag isn't there, you're out of luck.

Comment: Indeed. On the page in question, the [canonical link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element) is set to http://eatocracy.cnn.com/2013/08/02/fda-sets-gluten-free-labeling-standards/, i.e. the bare URL without parameters, which seems to make sense in this case.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer.  Hopefully most of the sites I wind up crawling will be SEO-friendly.  The canonical link will at least help me in reducing the amount of data re-processing I encounter, whenever it's available anyway.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to tell.  The parameters (after the `?` and before the `#`) are passed to the web server, and it's up to the web server what it does with them, and whether they affect the returned page or not.

(The pieces after the `#` are not given to the server, and can't affect the HTML that the server returns, but might be used by JavaScript to modify the page as seen by the user.)

Answer (score 0):

No, even with your example the page is being changed so that the form identifies who you have clicked to reply to.

The webserver can do what it likes with the parameters you pass in the request (items after `?` and before `#`).

The string after `#` denotes the anchor on the page which the browser should scroll to.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
function PagesAreIdentical($pointer1, $pointer2) {
    $headerArray1 = get_headers($pointer1);
    $headerArray2 = get_headers($pointer2):
    if($headerArray1['Content-Length'] == $headerArray2['Content-Length'])
    {
        if(file_get_contents($pointer1) != file_get_contents($pointer2))
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    else return false;
}
```